# Creating observables that do IO work

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have several resources in my app I need to load and dump into my database on first launch. I want to do this parallely.

So i created an observable wrapper around reading a file.

```
@Override
public Observable<List<T>> loadDataFromFile() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<T>> subscriber) {
            LOG.info("Starting load from file for %s ON THREAD %d" + type, Thread.currentThread().getId());
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                Gson gson = JsonConverter.getExplicitGson();
                inputStream = resourceWrapper.openRawResource(resourceId);
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                List<T> tList = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, type);

                subscriber.onNext(tList);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
                LOG.info("Completed load from file for " + type);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("An error occurred loading the file");
                subscriber.onError(e);
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However its not asynchronous, There are two approaches to making this asynchronous that i see:

1) Do the asynchrony inside the observable Spawn a new thread or use a callback based file reading api.

2) Use a scheduler to do the work on an I/O thread,

Again for the DB i have to create my own observable that wraps the databases Api and there is a synchronous and asynchronous version with a callback.

So what is the correct way of creating observables that do i/o work?

Secondly How can i use these observables in a chain to read these files all in parallel, then for each store the contents in the DB. I want to receive an onCompleted event when the entire process is complete for all my reference data.

Comment: Check out DataFetcher: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java

Comment: Im not sure how that relates to rx observables?

Comment: you don't even need to create an anonymous `onSubscribe`, you can pass a Callable, which handles the callback part (exceptions included) for you

Comment: as a matter of fact, I would actually use a `just()` with the resourceId, and then a map function to transform it into the file

Comment: @njzk2 how will i make these in paralell, that will all run synchronously

Comment: Doing IO in parallel might just slow things down due to contention. In series is the right way generally for fast IO.

Answer (score 2):

One good thing about RX is you can control on what thread your "work" is done. You can use

```
subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

If you want to load resources in parallel I suggest using the merge (or mergeDelayError) operator.

Assuming you have a function

```
Observable<List<T>> loadDataFromresource(int resID)
```

to load one resource, you could first create a list of observables for each resource

```
for (int i=0 ; i<10; i++) {               
    obsList.add(loadDataFromresource(i+1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
}
```

associating a scheduler with each observable. Merge the observables using

```
Observable<List<T>> mergedObs = Observable.merge(obsList);
```

Subscribing to the resulting observable should then load the resources in parallel. If you'd like to delay errors until the end of the merged observable then use

```
Observable<List<T>> mergedObs = Observable.mergeDelayError(obsList);
```

Comment: Ok so i did that but the probably is the work is being done sequentially i want to load all them in parallel

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, this is what i essentially did but it felt wrong as i am having to creating a list of observables. Other examples implied i could do this solely with flat map but still be in parallel

Comment: I was also unsure whether its ok to insert subcribeOn on the middle of the chain. So does that subscribe on affect only the loading of that resource, what i use subscribe on again downstream?

Comment: subscribeOn is just another operator (it returns an Observable) so there's no reason you can't use it in the middle of the chain. You could use a flatmap if you preferred I'm not sure how you could delay the error using that method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java developer, but in C# this is basically how this kind of code should be structured:

```
public IObservable<string> LoadDataFromFile()
{
    return
        Observable.Using(
            () => new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open),
            fs =>
                Observable.Using(
                    () => new StreamReader(fs),
                    sr => Observable.Start(() => sr.ReadLine())));

}
```

Hopefully you can adapt from that.